# Why isn't it adding my numbers correctly

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to add 100 numbers in an array together this is my code:
the numbers from 17 to 117 should add up to a lot more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
int* number = malloc(101*sizeof(int));
int num = 0;    

while (num != 101){
    number[num] = 17 + num;
    num = num + 1;
};


num = 0;

while(num != 101){
    printf(" %d \n", number[num]);
    num = num + 1;
}

num = 0;
int sum = 0;
while (num != 101){
    number[num] = 17;
    sum = sum + number[num];
    num = num + 1;

}

printf(" %d \n ", sum );

return 0;
}
```

The bottom print statement gives me a value of 1717

Comment: What do you think the result should be?

Comment: 101 times 17 equals 1717, what do you see wrong with that?

Comment: To be clear `number[num] = 17;` overwrites previously set value.

Comment: Why are you even using an array for this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
while (num != 101){
    number[num] = 17;
    sum = sum + number[num];
```

remove the second line which has been resetting everything to 17

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in this additional line:

```
number[num] = 17;
```

which unconditionally replaces the correct number in the array with 17. Remove that line to fix your issue.

Of course, you don't need an array or a loop to do this, since it's the sum of an [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression):

```
int sum = (start - end)(start + end) / 2;
```

Also, it is more correct to cast `void*` to `int*` in the allocation statement:

```
int* number = (int*)malloc(101*sizeof(int));
```

In fact, with gcc it doesn't even compile without the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 101 numbers, not 100:

Imagine that instead of:

```
int num = 0;
while (num != 101)
```

You write:

```
int num = 0;
while (num != 11)
```

You would be adding the 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Those are 10 numbers in total.

In C it is idiomatic to write the upper limit with `< LIMIT` to fix this issue:

```
int num = 0;
while (num < 100)
```

Note that, also idiomatically, the first value is number 0.

Maybe you have a VisualBasic background, and that's why you felt the need to create an array of 101 elements to add 100 numbers. In C you do not need such nonsense. The C way of writing this loop would be:

```
int* number = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
for (num = 0; num < 100; ++num)
{
    number[num] = ...;
}
```